# WPF window from WinForms application is now shown

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, window, winforms-interop

I'm developing a WinForms application. I click a button to show a WPF window, executing the following code:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window();
    ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
    window.Show();
}
```

- When I launch the window **for the first time the windows appears.**
- Then, if I close the window and **try to show it again, the window does not appear.**

As a cue, playing with the code I discovered that **if I create the WPF window twice, the window is always shown**.

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window();
    window = new Window(); // creating the window twice WORKS!!
    ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
    window.Show();
}
```

So it makes me think about an issue with the dispatcher, or something that is done in the window constructor.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't repro the problem.  WPF needs the dispatcher loop, there's a lot of stuff that can't work correctly without it.  You'll have to use ShowDialog().

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, the issue is not reproduced in a clean application. Seems that in my real application I'm experiencing some multithread interaction. Anyway calling ShowDialog() I see the same behavior.